# Comparing collections with different item types

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, bdd, fluent-assertions

I have two collections with different item types, for example:

```
var collection1 = new List<Type1>();
var collection2 = new List<Type2>();
```

Is it possible to **assert that two collections with different item types contain equal items in any order using my own equality comparer** with the FluentAssertions?

The most related example from [the official FA documentation](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/wiki#collections) considers that both collections are the same type:

```
persistedCustomers.Should().Equal(customers, (c1, c2) => c1.Name == c2.Name);
```

One possible solution to use this approach for my situation is to create a new `List<Type1>` collection based on items from the `collection2` and use it instead of `customers` in the example above.
But sometimes it's just not possible and actually smells like an overhead.

I'm wondering if there is a similar approach that uses FA elegance like the above one but suitable for the collections with different item types?

**UPDATE 1** (trying to use @DennisDoomen suggestion):

Let's take more specific example.
Suppose we have a `List<DateTime>` of expected values that represents dates of a single month:

```
    var expectation = new List<DateTime>();
```

A testing method returns a `List<int>` of day numbers:

```
    var actual = new List<int>();
```

We want to assert that the set of day numbers returned by testing method is the same as a set composed from DateTime.Day values of the expectation list, i.e.:

```
    Assert.AreEqual(expectation[0].Day, actual[0]);
    Assert.AreEqual(expectation[1].Day, actual[1]);
...
    Assert.AreEqual(expectation[expectation.Count - 1].Day, actual[actual.Count - 1]);
```

(but without the ordering restriction which I don't how to demonstrate in this example).

I'm trying to use @DennisDoomen suggestion in this way:

```
    actual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(
        expectation,
        options => options.Using<int>(
            ctx => ctx.Subject.Should().Be(ctx.Expectation.Day)).WhenTypeIs<int>());
```

The problem is that `ctx.Expectation` here is a type of `int`, not a `DateTime`, so I can't get `DateTime.Day` anyhow.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ShouldBeEquivalentTo` is what you need. By default it will ensure that each collection contains items that are structurally equivalent in any order. You can then use the `Using`/`When` options to define how `Type1` and `Type2` should be compared. Something like:

```
collection1.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(collection2, options => options 
   .Using<Type1>(t1 => ctx.Subject.Should().Be(ctx.Expectation) 
   .WhenTypeIs<Type1>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @DennisDoomen! I've updated my question with a new problem I'm facing after using your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, but I've never talked about `ShouldBeEquivalentTo`, it was your suggestion. What I meant from the very beginning of my question (and it's even bolded) is **using my own equality comparer** to define custom equality rules between 2 different item types. And as a most closest example I've pointed to `.Should().Equal(customers, (c1, c2) => c1.Name == c2.Name)` that lets use custom predicate for equality checking. So my update is not a new question, it's just a more specific example to clear my point.

Comment: My pleasure and thanks for answering, though :) So is there an approach for my situation in FA?

Comment: No, not really. You could implement a custom `IAssertionRule` and add that to the `options` when calling `ShouldBeEquivalentTo` though, but that's a bit more work.